# How can I sort my SQL records in PHP by Month?

Tags: php, sql, date

I have a table in my database, that stores statistical data. Structure is like this:

```
---------------------------------------------
| travelTimes                               |
---------------------------------------------
| ID       | INT(6)  | *Primary key*        |
| goesfrom | INT(6)  | *location ID*        |
| goesto   | INT(6)  | *location ID*        |
| length   | INT(6)  | *time it takes*      |
| time     | Date    | *date of the record* |
---------------------------------------------
```

I am trying to display these data on a PHP page grouped by the month of the `time` Column, loading these data to charts (if I have records from 3 different months, there should be 3 different charts).

**What do you think the best solution would be for this problem?**

I have tried loading the table to a PHP array(associative), and compare the dates that way, but php is quite unique as I understand. So this didn't work:

```
foreach($travelTimes as $travelTime){
    if(date("m", strtotime($travelTime["time"])) == date("m")){
        // I would sort here the current month's records
    }
}
```

Also there was a problem at the end of the years, because my tries ignored the year change.

Comment: I think you need to add data based on year and month.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not add `ORDER BY` to your query?

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't see where the ORDER BY in it self would help me compare the dates in PHP

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Add the rows to an associative array like `$chart["2020-01"][] = $travelTime; $chart["2020-02"][] = $travelTime;` then iterate over the `$chart` array... each item will be an array of rows that belong to that year-month.

Comment: The question asks: "How can I sort my SQL records in PHP by Month?" - that's why I've asked why you didn't sort the records in the query. What else is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is a good one, so I adapted it to make it fill an array with every month and its associated travelTimes:

```
$monthlyTravelTimes = [];
foreach($travelTimes as $travelTime) {
    $month = date("m", strtotime($travelTime["time"]);
    $monthlyTravelTimes[$month] = $travelTime;
}
```

You can get the travel times for the current month via:

```
$monthlyTravelTimes[date('m')];
```

Note: This doesn't handle years at all, but could easily be adapted by replacing `'m'` by `'Y-m'`.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *, MONTH(time) as timeMonth FROM travelTimes ORDER BY timeMonth

Untested but might work

Answer (score 0):

Someone added an answer that got deleted since, but his idea helped find a solution:

`SELECT *, MONTH(time) as timeMonth, YEAR(time) as timeYear FROM travelTimes ORDER BY time;`

With this, I can simply compare strings in PHP like:

```
if($travelTime["timeYear"] == "2021" && $travelTime["timeMonth"] == "10"){}
```

Without problems.

Comment: Apologies that was me :/ Removed by accident. Added it back